# Output custom attribute in Password Reset Custom Policy

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have a custom policy for Password Reset. The one that comes with the starter pack of custom policies on Azure B2C. I want it to output two custom attributes that I already defined. I made those attributes work with custom signup/signin and edif profile, I can see them in the jwt after execute those policies. But I don't know how to output them with the Password Reset policy. Is it possible? Or the user must be logged in to make it work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding a new orchestration step to the "PasswordReset" user journey after the password is saved by the "LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId" technical profile at step 2 and before the JWT is issued by the "JwtIssuer" technical profile at step 3.

This new orchestration step reads the user, including the custom claims, by invoking the "AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" technical profile:

(I am assuming you have added the custom claims as `<OutputClaim />`s to this technical profile.)

```xml
<UserJourney Id="PasswordReset">
  <OrchestrationSteps>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="PasswordResetUsingEmailAddressExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="NewCredentials" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
  </OrchestrationSteps>
  <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
</UserJourney>
```

You must then add the custom claims as `<OutputClaim />`s to the "PasswordReset" relying party policy:

```xml
<RelyingParty>
  <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="PasswordReset" />
  <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
    <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="myCustomClaim1" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="myCustomClaim2" />
    </OutputClaims>
    <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
  </TechnicalProfile>
</RelyingParty>
```